# Empty automatically linked to object when created

Tags: objects, parent

I have a problem: when I create an empty and move it close to an object, it automatically sticks to it and I can't move or deform any of them independantly from each other. No parenting is defined, I don't understand... do I make a mistake?
(I use Blender 2.78)

Comment: try turning off proportional editing.

Comment: That's it, thank you ... I guess I pressed [O] by accident, I didn't know this shortcut yet. I'm a beginner ! :)